# JSON array values not being read by JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I’m reading X,Y Coordinates from MySQL Database.

2 files(I can post the connection file if needed): coordinate_array, and map.php

coordinate_array:  I am making a multidimensional arrays so I can  then use json_encode($desk). I only need x,y values for the JS/Jqueryt part.

**updated PHP code and JQuery CODE.. still does not work!?**

```
    <?php
          include 'db_conn.php';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $coordinate_sql = "SELECT x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$coordinate_sql);

    //see if query is good
    if($result === false) {
        die(mysqli_error()); 
    }

    //array that will have number of desks in map area
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  

        //get desk array count
        $desk[] = array('x' => $row['x_coord'],                                 
                        'y' => $row['y_coord']);
    } //end while loop
          echo json_encode($desk);  //encode array
?>
```

**The code above gives me this as the result for the array:**

```
[{"x":"20","y":"20"},{"x":"30","y":"30"},{"x":"40","y":"40"},{"x":"50","y":"50"}]
```

map.php : This is the part where is not entirely working. I'm trying to get the values from json_encode with JQuery but I get no output on screen.

Don't know which of these two I should use

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
 <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Need help here please

```
 <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="500"></canvas>          
 <script type="text/javascript">

                //I have no idea how to get the encoded values
    $.post('coordinate_array.php', {}, function(data) {
    results = JSON.parse(data);
        for(i = 0;i < results.length;i++) {
            Paint(results[i].x, results[i].y);
        }
    });
```

I want to execute this function

```
        //function to paint rectangles
        function Paint(x,y)
                {
                var ctx, cv;
                cv = document.getElementById('imageView');
                ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
                ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
                //x-axis,y-axis,x-width,y-width
                ctx.strokeRect(x, y, x+100 , y+100); 
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: You can use either of the jQuery includes - the first one requires that you have jQuery stored locally.

Comment: Have you at least managed to include jQuery successfully before the rest of your javascript and / or do you have any error messages in the console your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Note that mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) can replece the entire while loop

Comment: yes my JQuery is included well, the console error I get is : SCRIPT1008: Expected '{' after function(date)  .. I dont know!? @jeroen

Answer (score 0):

The JSON formal definition tends to have an *object* (or, key-associative-array: `{}`) as the root of any JSON object, as opposed to an array (`[]`).

To wrap it inside one associative object:

```
$deskOutput = array("coords" => $desk);
echo json_encode($deskOutput);  //encode array
```

Then, on the JavaScript side, you will just need to get "`each(data.coords,`" and you'll have your array.

For that matter, it seems like you're putting unnecessary complexity in your array structure at the PHP level. How about this?

```
$desk[] = array("x" => $row['x_coord'], "y" => $row['y_coord']));
```

That will create just one object for each x/y set. I'll leave it to you to figure out how you could simplify your JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that first part; the OP's json validates on http://jsonlint.com/ at least so I would say it is wrong.

Comment: Hm...I'll admit I'm surprised to find that at least one browser parse method takes an array just fine; some tools I know have run into issues with that though.

Comment: guys I updated my code check it out.. but I get this error once I validate the JSON on jsonlint.com : Parse error on line 1:
$.post('coordinate_a
^
Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score 0):

First just make $desk like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  

    //get desk array count
    $desk[] = array('x' => $row['x_coord'], 'y' => $row['y_coord']);
}
echo json_encode($desk);
```

And call the php script like so:

```
$.post('coordinate_array.php', {}, function(data) {
    results = JSON.parse(data);
    for(i = 0;i < results.length;i++) {
        Paint(results[i].x, results[i].y);
    }
});
```

I'm going to test this really quick to make sure I got everything right.
Edit: Okay, I tested this, it works.

Comment: hey, I tried it and still nothing? I used the validator from jsonlint.com and says error message like so : Parse error on line 1:
$.post('coordinate_a
^
Expecting '{', '['  .. is there something suposed to go inside those brackets?

Comment: When did you use it? I had a syntax error in it shortly after I posted it (but fixed it like 15 hours ago), but make sure you use it exactly as is. Except for however you call it.

Comment: This definitely works though. Did you change the php I posted too? Also, obvious question, but you have jquery included on the page?